# Testing DoFn Apache Crunch

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-crunch

I am very new to Apache Crunch. This is the first test case I have written. Currently I am writing test cases for DoFn but it says NullPointerException.

```java
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions;
import org.apache.crunch.Emitter;
import org.apache.crunch.Pair;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class OutputResultTest {

  @Mock
  InMemoryEmitter <String>  emitter = new InMemoryEmitter<>();

  @Test
  public void TestProcess(){
    OutputResult outputResult = new OutputResult();
    //String expected = "Thor Odinson scored 97.8";
    Pair<String,Double> input = Pair.of("Thor Odinson",97.8);
    outputResult.process(input,emitter);
    assertEquals(expected,emitter.getOutput());
    //verify(emitter).emit("Thor Odinson scored 97.8");//this works
    //verifyNoMoreInteractions(emitter);//this works
  }
}
```

Comment: Which line is the NPE on, and what is `OutputResult`?

Comment: The NPE is on line `verify(emitter).emit()` and OutputResult is a class that extends DoFn. It takes pair as input and emits String as output.

Comment: You're not telling your mock what to do when emitter.emit is called

Comment: I changed the `private Emitter<String> emitter` to `InMemoryEmitter <String>  emitter= new InMemoryEmitter<String >(); ` and the code worked with verify. Although that is enough for now but the code does not work with `assertEquals(expected,emitter);` . It says "assertEquals() between objects of inconvertible types 'String' and 'List<String>' ". I have no idea why.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use an ArgumentCaptor to grab the data being sent to your mocked emitter, and then assert on that.

Comment: It was my mistake. I actually wrote `assertEquals(expected,emitter.getOutput())` . Forgot to update. Only then it showed the previously written error. I have edited the above file to show the new updated file.